# Can't change node version - Windows

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

Working on windows x64

Tryied different thing to use node version 10.19.0 but nothing work.

What I dont understand is following behavior

I installed `nvm`

`node -v` return v12.16.1

`nvm list` return

```
10.19.0
5.4.0
```

should'nt `nvm list` return avaible version of nodejs?`

Edit:

I tryed `nvm use 10.19.0` but doesnt seem to work

`nvm use 12.16.1` return `node v12.16.1 (64-bit) is not installed.`

Answer (score 1):

I had nodeJs installed in path

`C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Installing new version of node with `nvm` was installing in

`C:\Users\{myname}\AppData\Roaming\nvm`

I changed windows variable `NVM_SYMLINK` to path 
`C:\Users\{myname}\AppData\Roaming\nvm`